# Nginx + SSL + Rails + Juggernaut (Node.js) + Engineyard

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy, node.js, socket

I have two different applications on the same server. One of them is running on the 80 port (mydomain.com), another on the port 443 (sub.mydomain.com) and has wildcard certificate.

The first application is only for information purposes and don't need websockets support. The second application should have secure websockets support (wss protocol).

I tried to set up juggernaut gem (for websockets) for my rails app with nginx server on the engineyard cloud, but i have one problem. Engineyard cloud provide only two opened ports: 80 and 443. I know that nginx do not fully support http 1.1 reverse proxing, so i can't use proxing from nginx for redirects websockets requests to the specific local port (in my case this port is 8080).

I tried use HAProxy and it's work for me when i use only unsecure websockets, but i need to support secure websockets. As i know in this case i should use something like STunnel for tunneling my https request and than use HAProxy, but when i test it - i saw that the server has to work several times slower and i still did not work to use the secure socket connection :(

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe someone will tell how to set up nginx for multiple applications (one of them should work via https) and secure websockets using only two ports (80 and 443).

p.s. Also i used a node-http-proxy, in this case i was able to set up proxy for different nginx applications but i do not get run websockets (happened only for "handshake" via nginx, not for "switching protocols")

Answer (score 0):

A normal reverse proxy won't work for websocket connections. There is a patch for Nginx that adds a tcp proxy feature which is compatible with websockets.

Good article on the combination here:
http://blog.mixu.net/2011/08/13/nginx-websockets-ssl-and-socket-io-deployment/